# LE audio doesn't work with bluez5.71 on ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, 23.10, bluez

My purpose is to play music from a le audio cell phone, and it will be transported to a le audio device.

BTW, my Ubuntu version is 23.10.

I connected a controller device which supports LE Audio by UART, then

```
bluetoothctl 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# hci0 new_settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn cis-central cis-peripheral 
[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller AB:89:67:45:23:01 Pairable: yes
advertise on
[bluetooth]# hci0 advertising_added: instance 1
[bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller AB:89:67:45:23:01 SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
[bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller AB:89:67:45:23:01 ActiveInstances: 0x01 (1)
[bluetooth]# Advertising object registered
[bluetooth]# Tx Power: off
[bluetooth]# Name: off
[bluetooth]# Appearance: off
[bluetooth]# Discoverable: on
[bluetooth]# RSI: on
endpoint.register 00002bc9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 0x06
[/local/endpoint/ep0] Auto Accept (yes/no): y
[/local/endpoint/ep0] Max Transports (auto/value): a
[/local/endpoint/ep0] Locations: 1
[/local/endpoint/ep0] Supported Context (value): 1
[/local/endpoint/ep0] Context (value): 1
[/local/endpoint/ep0] CIG (auto/value): a
[/local/endpoint/ep0] CIS (auto/value): a
Failed register endpoint
[bluetooth]#
```

When I register the endpoint, it fails, I am not sure why this happens.
Please give me some hints, thanks.